# Nullable datetime value

Tags: c#

Can a `DateTime` value be `NULL`?

I have this code:

From here I inherit my variable

```
namespace Transakcija
{
     public class Line
     {
        public System.DateTime DateOfProduction { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Then for each loop:

```
foreach (var rw_det in dt_stavke.Rows)
{
    var list = new List<Transakcija.Line>();
    var l = new Transakcija.Line();

     //DateOfProduction
    if (rw_det["DPRO02"].ToString().Length <= 0)
    {
        l.DateOfProduction = default(DateTime);
    }
    else
    {
        l.DateOfProduction = new DateTime();
        prod_date = rw_det["DPRO02"].ToString();
        DateTime pro_date = DateTime.ParseExact(prod_date, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string p_date = pro_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        l.DateOfProduction = DateTime.Parse(p_date);
    }
}
```

So the value `l.DateOfProduction` needs to be null.  I have tried this:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
l.DateOfProduction = (DateTime)dt;
```

But I got error: `nullable object must have a value`

So is this possible or do I have to pass the minimum `datetime` value to the variable?

Comment: Your `else` branch in the second sample looks weird. The constructor `new DateTime()` doesn't seem to exist and the whole line seems to be unnecessary. And why are you parsing a string into a date, then formatting it into another string, then parsing it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assigne a nullable `DateTime`  by using the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxxazwb):

```
DateTime? dt = new Nullable<DateTime>();
```

You can check if a nullable type is `null` by using the [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
if(dt.HasValue)
{
    // now you can safely use dt.Value as DateTime, 
    // otherwise accessing the Value property raises an InvalidOperationException
    DateTime otherDate = dt.Value;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but can I do this: l.DateOfProduction = otherDate;

Comment: @CrBruno: Yes, `dt.Value` is just a DateTime. So you can use `l.DateOfProduction = dt.Value;` when you've checked first that `dt.HasValue`. But i recommend to change the datatype of `DateOfProduction` to `DateTime?` if possible.

Answer (score 8):

`DateTime` is a value type, so no it can never be `null`. If you need a "no value" value, use a `Nullable<DateTime>` or for short `DateTime?`

Comment: So I have to pass min value you say?

Comment: @CrBruno That's not what he said at all.

Comment: How to write that? Help guys!

Comment: @CrBruno BrokenGlass is giving you the information you need...  Do some searches on using null able.  You have your information...shouldn't really require being spoon fed.

Answer (score 1):

You can have DateTime Nullable this way

```
DateTime? dtNullable = new Nullable<DateTime>(); 

if(dtNullable.HasValue)
 l.DateOfProduction = dtNullable.Value;
```

PS: example if you passing a non nullable DateTime to a Nullable DateTime then it will require casting

Like this

```
DateTime? nullableDateTime = (DateTime?)nonNullableDateTime;
```

Comment: i have updated the answer that will check if it has value before you use the nullable

Comment: I wrote this and I got min date?

Comment: @CrBruno yes it will pass the default as per my example, if you want to pass DateTime.Now then please let me know I can update my answer for you

Comment: No thanks, i didn't know that it will pass min value, i tough that it will pass null or 0, but this is the same as l.DateOfProduction = default(DateTime); so i can't get "null" only min date?